# How do I convert a list of int to a list of Nullable<int>?

Tags: c#

I have something that takes `List<int?>` and I have a `List<int>`.

I can write:

```
var items = value.Select(num => (int?) num).ToList();
```

But is that really the simplest method?

Comment: It might be better to write Nullable<int> in your question since it's confusing.

Comment: Seems to be simply enought, I wouldnt do it better.

Comment: I believe so. That's what I'd do to convert List<int> to List<Nullable<int>>

Comment: For your information: This is better suited on the page for Code-Reviews than on SO

Comment: The only simplest solution would be to *not* do the conversion. Any other solution does essentially the same thing,eg .ConvertAll<>, Cast<>/ToList<>, Select<>/ToList all enumerate the original list and create a new one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Would this work?

```
var items = value.Cast<int?>().ToList();
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the original code, probalby resulting in the same IL code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `Select` requires another instance of `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator` whereas `Cast` just loops and returns `yield return (TResult)((object)current);`. So `Enumerable.Cast` could be a little bit more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use [`List.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
List<int?> items = value.ConvertAll<int?>(i => i);
```

It works even in .NET 2. Apart from that there is no advantage, so i would stay with LINQ (`Enumerable.Cast` as suggested by Tamim Salem) since it's more usable and readable.

But if you need a `List<int?>` instead of a `List<int>` Why don't you use one in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var result1 = list.ConvertAll<int?>(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
List<int?> newList = oldList.ConvertAll<int?>(i => i);
```

Although it probably does near-enough the same thing underneath.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<Nullable<int>> b = new List<int?>();

for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
{
    b.Add(new Nullable<int>(a[i]));
}
```

In case you want to omit lambdas and projection.

Comment: How is this simpler? 7 lines instead of 1?

Comment: Dear sir, if you think simplicity is measured with lines of code then you are an idiot. Let me show you some simplicity with one line of code - int count = Enumerable.Range(0, 500).AsParallel().Select(x => new { Id = x }).Where(x => { if (x.Id % 2 == 0 || x.Id % 5 == 0) return true; return false; }).Count(x => x.Id < 200); Please let me know how you will debug this if something goes wrong. This is a simple example, imagine this in production code.

Comment: If we skip the initialization of the lists(as everybody above did) it still can be written with one line - for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++) { b.Add(new Nullable<int>(i)) }; Is it simpler ? I think not.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding casts and conversions

```
List<int?> nullInts = new List<int?>();
listInts.ForEach(i => nullInts.Add(new int?(i)));
```

Comment: How do you avoid casts and conversions here? The conversion operators actually do exactly the same thing as your code does - create a new nullable instance containing the non-nullable value

Comment: Just ildasm your code and mine, and see differences, e.g. look up for Converter in your ildasm code.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself doing this much, you could implement @TamimSalem's solution in an extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    public static List<T?> ToNullableList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T: struct
    {
        return sequence.Cast<T?>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var items = value.ToNullableList();
```